# Mi APP funciona el firebase en el emulador pero no en el dispositivo

Tags: android, kotlin, app

Hola como ya lo mencione en el titulo mi app no me ingresa datos a firebase desde mi dispositivo pero si funciona correctamente el firebase desde el emulador.

este es el codigo que tengo:

```
private var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
private lateinit var pru: EditText
private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
lateinit var cxAdView: AdView
lateinit var dbReference: DatabaseReference


private fun Guardar(na:String){

    var df = 3
    var cc = "Ticket" + df
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val myRef = database.getReference("Tickets").child(user?.uid!!)
    myRef.child("Conteo").setValue(df)
    myRef.child(cc).setValue(na)
    /*user.let{
        val name = user!!.displayName
        val email = user!!.email
        val photoUrl = user!!.photoUrl
    }

    myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
                for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val email = ds.child("Conteo").getValue(String::class.java)
                    val name = ds.child("Ticket").getValue(String::class.java)
                    Log.d("TAG", "$email / $name")
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
        }
    })*/


}
```

ya comprobe las variables y la funcion, funcionando ambas.

¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: No estoy muy seguro si firebase es igual, pero probaste de sacar el SHA-1 de tu dispositivo movil y agregarlo a tu proyecto de firebase? 

https://medium.com/pen-bold-kiln-press/sha-1-android-studio-ec02fb893e72

Comment: Si ya tengo el SHA1 ya que uso auth para firebase y si me conecto el problemas es al agregar datos.

Comment: Hola amigo ya revisaste tus reglas de seguridad de tu base de datos firebase.
Tal vez no escribe desde tu dispositivo porque no estas autentificado de manera correcta y en el emulador si.
Espero te sirva